# what is the difference between flex box and media query?

Tags: html, css

I'am confused about the difference between flex box and media query?

couldn't find answers in google. 
I know we use media query in flex box but still i dont know the differnce

Comment: You don't "use media query in flex box" necessarly. They are different things.

Comment: [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) are used to style different breakpoints and media types and [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox) is just a type of element style.  Also you don't use a media query in flexbox but you might use flexbox in your media queries

Comment: Can you elaborate why you think they are the same thing? They have literally nothing in common.

Comment: it's like the difference between and apple and a pen.

Answer (score 5):

**Flex box is a layout model**

It's a way of laying out elements on the page so that they are flexible in size and orientation. Flexbox has no real basis in print. It is a layout model that was uniquely created for the web, and really only makes sense for the web.

Flexbox is used via properties and values for a specific ruleset:

```
.someSelector {
display: flex; /*a new value for the display property*/
flex-direction: column; /*a new property*/
}
```

**Media Queries are a an extension of Media Types**
Media queries are a popular technique for delivering a tailored style sheet to different devices.

In HTML4 and CSS2, you could send a stylesheet based on the type of viewing medium, but not on particular properties of that medium.

Media queries allow you apply stylesheets based on properties of a particular medium, as well as the type of medium:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen and (max-width: 499px)" href="mobile.css">
```

Not only that, media queries can go inside of a stylesheet, as well:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 499px) {
  body {
    font-size: .8rem;
  }
}
```

Flexbox goes inside of a ruleset. Media Query is outside of a ruleset.

Flexbox tells an element how to take up space. Media Query tells you how the content is being viewed.

Also, flexbox + media queries = awesome layouts

Answer (score 1):

Media query is a CSS technique introduced in CSS3.
It uses the @media rule to include a block of CSS properties only if a certain condition is true.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  body {
    background-color: lightblue;
  }
}
```

Flexbox is a new layout mode in CSS3.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background-color: red;
}

.flex-container > div {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 75px;
  font-size: 30px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="flex-container">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>  
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>  
  <div>7</div>
  <div>8</div>
  <div>9</div>  
  <div>10</div>
  <div>11</div>
  <div>12</div>  
</div>

<p>Try resizing the browser window.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you are not answering *the difference*, you are simply defining each one

Comment: you can see a difference in the snippet